# Angular 3rd party library interaction

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm having a weird interaction between two widely used libraries inside my Angular 4 application: `ng-bootstrap` ([ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)) and `Highcharts` ([Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com)).

I have this `metering` component containing two child components: `data-selection` and `metering-chart`, as so:

```
<div>
    <data-selection (selectedEntities)="onSelectedData()"></data-selection>
    <button (click)="loadMeteringData()">Load Data</button>
    <metering-chart *ngIf="chartData" [chartData]="chartData"></metering-chart>
</div>
```

Where `data-selection` contains the following -*stripped*- template:

```
[...]
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        [...]
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
                   name="dpStart" 
                   [(ngModel)]="startDateModel" 
                   ngbDatepicker 
                   #startDate="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-addon" 
                 (click)="startDate.toggle()">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            [...]
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
[...]
```

And the `metering-chart` component contains:

```
<chart [options]="options" 
    (load)="createChartObject($event.context)"
    (drilldown)="drilledDown($event)"
    (drillup)="drilledUp($event)" style="width:100%; display: inline-block; "></chart>
```

> The `metering` component is a `router-outlet` declared in a `Routes`
>   file, which is in turn imported by a `RoutingModule`. This
>   `RoutingModule` imports `SharedModule` (where both child components:
>   `data-selection` and `metering-chart` are declared and exported), and
>   is imported by the main `AppModule`.

Since initially `metering`'s `chartData` is undefined, the `metering-chart` component is not displayed. During this time, the datepickers work like a charm.

However, it is only when I click the button to load the chart's data and the chart itself, that the datepicker's popup containers become unresponsive.

I have tried to create a plunker where the issue was reproduced, but to no avail... However, here's a gif showing what's going on:

[image: Weird library interaction]

As you can see, the model is being updated when the date is typed directly into the input field. However, clicking on any of the dates yield no result whatsoever.

I'm using the following:

`Angular v. 4.0.1`
`angular2-highcharts v. 0.5.5`
`ng-bootstrap v. 1.0.0-alpha.27`

I could provide a ton more information regarding architecture or component interaction, but there's so much of it that, if anything critical should be missing from my question, please tell me and I'll provide it all.

Comment: It's very unlikely that a solution can be suggested here without a plunk or other http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you cannot replicate the problem, how can the answerer do this?

Comment: I'm aware of the difficulty. I was hoping such an interaction could spark some idea on a brighter, broader mind... Believe me I have tried to replicate the issue on a plunker, as I understood perfectly well the ambiguity of my question. Nonetheless, I hoped for someone to shed some light on the matter... After all, Plunker hasn't always been around...

Comment: Plunker wasn't around, but MCVE is required by SO rules, and working example seriously increases chances of having someone who will spare some time to debug a problem. Since this isn't Angular or JS theoretical question and Highcharts/Bootstrap/whatever add too many moving parts, this can't be solved by deduction alone (some questions can but not this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from Alios' answer which links to ng-boostrap's GitHub issue page:

The problem does not reside in a faulty interaction between libraries, but rather in a wrong creation of the `chart` element. Apparently it was being created inside an Angular Zone, thus triggering change detection on every event handler.

The solution was to remove the chart creation & update event bindings from the `metering-chart` component template, leaving it like so:

```
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

And leaving the the chart creation, data update, and drilldown/up events to be handled outside the angular zone:

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    // Create or Update the chart
})
```

Furthermore, all the event bindings defined in the previous `<chart>` element have to be redefined inside the component's logic and options object.